# The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: []("temp")

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety, flutter-futurebuilder, fluttermap

I'm using the FutureBuilder to get future data from the API
My json is map type, so whenever i'm trying to change the snapshot.data to map type variable to access specific api option it's showing error. The below error i'm getting. I'm unable to store it.

> A value of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'.
> Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'.

```dart
 

    import 'dart:collection';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:climate_app/util/utils.dart' as util;
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Climatic extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ClimaticState createState() => _ClimaticState();
}

class _ClimaticState extends State<Climatic> {
  // late Map content;
  // so now if we want to call out getWheather() to provide us data then we have to call it into an async function like this
  void showData() async {
    Map _whetherData = await getWheather(util.appID, util.defaultCity);
    print(_whetherData.toString());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Climatic"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        actions: [
          IconButton(onPressed: () => showData(), icon: Icon(Icons.menu))
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        // we use the stack widget so that we can add more widget on top of each other
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Image.asset(
              "images/umbrella.png",
              width: 490.0,
              height: 1200.0,
              fit: BoxFit
                  .fill, // we used the fit proerty so that our picture get's fitted into our widget in every way
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 10.9, 20.0, 0.0),
            child: Text(
              "Dhaka",
              style: cityStyle(),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            // we are adding another image widget into our stack widget
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Image.asset("images/light_rain.png"),
          ),
          // container which will contain our weather data
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 400.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            child: updateTempWidget("1337179"),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

// into our _climaticState we are crating our future function to parse the api data as known to do
  Future<Map> getWheather(String appID, String city) async {
    String apiURL =
        "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=$city&appid=${util.appID}&units=metric";
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(apiURL));
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  Widget updateTempWidget(String city) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getWheather(util.appID, city),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          // what we get all of the json data, we setup widget etc.
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            Map content = snapshot.data!;
            print(content);
            return Container(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(content["main"]["temp"]),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("Error");
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        });
  }
}

TextStyle cityStyle() {
  return TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.9, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic);
}

TextStyle tempStyle() {
  return TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
      fontSize: 49.0,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500);
}
```

Comment: It is not safe it use `future: getWheather(util.appID, city),` inside StateFullWidget. It will recall the api on every state changes. Can you point where are you getting the error now and I will recommend to follow this [doc example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: Map content = snapshot.data!; exactly here is the problem

Comment: try `= snapshot.data??{};`

Comment: Map content = snapshot.data ??{}; problem solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Providing an empty map on null case,

```dart
Map content = snapshot.data??{};
```

Also instead of `throw "";` check `snapshot.hasError` and last return a widget.

```dart
FutureBuilderMap<dynamic, dynamic>?(
  future: myFuture,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
       Map content =  snapshot.data??{};

  }
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("Error");
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
),
```

Find more about using [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: tried this way but not working. Same error is coming at the end. Showing still the problem in futurebuilder.

Comment: If you get error from Text, means there is something wrong on server-side or parsing data.

Comment: {
"coord": {
"lon": 90.4167,
"lat": 24.1667
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 804,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "overcast clouds",
"icon": "04n"
}
],
"base": "stations",
"main": {
"temp": 30.96,
"feels_like": 37.96,
"temp_min": 30.96,
"temp_max": 30.96,
"pressure": 1002,
"humidity": 80,
"sea_level": 1002,
"grnd_level": 1000
},

Comment: see my api, it's basically a map api. So, when i'm parsing data through map function in the content for whole api so that  i can access any key value from it, then it's not working. If i remove map from here AsyncSnapshot<Map> then map content doesn't work. and i maintain this, it shows the same error

Comment: are you able see on console by print/debug statement

Comment: yes, i'm able to see

Comment: Can you provide full widget that will reproduce the same error. More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: now you can see my entire code